# Javascript and SVG. Is there a way to detect has text rendered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, svg

I got some amount of `svg` elements, which generated dynamically. It generated based on what text in `input` field.

Each break means new group element structured like that

```
<g>
  <svg>
     <text/>
     <rect/>
  </svg>
</g>
```

Also there is added font changing option. So, after type of font changes I need to re-draw `rect` under text, which sizes are depends on what I get on `text.getBBox()` data.

The problem is, when I change font for the first time (there is event fires, after you select other font type in `select` dropdown list) my rects are not re-draws, because of text has not rendered inside `<text>` elements, so is there way to check, is there all text rendered inside all `<text>` elements?

Here is illustartion of the problem

[image]

**UPD 1**:

This is not worked for me

```
someSvgTextBlocks.ready(function() { 
 //call redraw rects functions here
})
```

**UPD 2**:

Sadly, but Raphael's answer not helped me either:
[image]

**UPD 3**

I use Angularjs framework, so here's the code in angular way (i guess)

Directives view for svg stuff:

```
<svg ng-repeat="line in svgConfig.text track by $index">
    <g>
        <rect x="0" y="0" 
            ng-show="svgConfig.rectConfig[$index].active"
            ng-attr-height="{{svgConfig.rectConfig[$index].height}}" 
            ng-attr-width="{{svgConfig.rectConfig[$index].width}}" 
        >
        </rect>

        <text ng-attr-font-family="{{svgConfig.textConfig.fontFamily}}" 
            ng-attr-font-size="{{svgConfig.textConfig.fontSize}}"
            ng-attr-fill="{{svgConfig.textConfig.fontColor}}"
        >
            {{line}}
        </text>     

    </g>

</svg>
```

Directive itself:

```
app.directive('imageTxtSvgDirective', ['imageTxtSvgService', 'svgUtilsService', function(imageTxtSvgService, svgUtilsService) {

    /**
    * Set event bindings
    */
    var setDomBindings = function($scope, $element, $attrs){
        /**
        * Sets watch to detect changes in text, fontsize, font family to recalculate binded svg-data
        */
        $scope.$watchGroup(['svgConfig.text', 'svgConfig.textConfig.fontSize', 'svgConfig.textConfig.fontFamily', 'svgConfig.extras', 'svgConfig.rectsVisible'], function() {
            var domText = $element.find('text'),
                textExampleList = domText,
                textConfig = $scope.svgConfig.textConfig,
                font = textConfig.fontFamily,
                size = textConfig.fontSize;

            document.fonts.load(''+size + 'px ' + font+'').then(
                function(){
                    $scope.setSvgRectanglesConfig(textExampleList);     
                }
            );
        });
    }

    /*
    * Retruns initialized DOM element
    */
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: './app/shared/imageTextEditor/imageTxtSvgView.html',
        controller: 'imageTxtSvgController',
        transclude: true,
        link: setDomBindings
    };
}]);
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('imageTxtSvgController', ['$scope', 'imageTxtSvgService', '$filter', 'textConfigEnum', function($scope, imageTxtSvgService, $filter, textConfigEnum){

    /**
    * Returns config for each text line rect
    */
    $scope.setSvgRectanglesConfig = function(textAreaList){
        var me = this,
            numberOfElements = (textAreaList) ? textAreaList.length : 0;

        if (numberOfElements <= 0) {
            return;
        }

        $scope.svgConfig.rectConfig = imageTxtSvgService.getSvgRectListData(textAreaList, $scope.svgConfig.rectsVisible, $scope.svgConfig);
    };

    $scope.init = function(){
        // Fonts data
        $scope.textFonts = textConfigEnum.data;

        // Container for svg settings
        $scope.svgConfig = {
            text:'',
            textConfig: {
                fontFamily: $filter('getTextConfigByType')(textConfigEnum.info.Arial).fontFamily,
                fontSize: 20,
                fontDecoration: null,
                fontWeigth: null,
                fontColor:'black'
            },
            rectsVisible: true,
            rectConfig: [],

        };
    };

    $scope.init();
}]);
```

Service:

```
    app.service('imageTxtSvgService', ['$rootScope', 'svgUtilsService', function($rootScope, svgUtilsService){

    this.getSvgRectObject = function(data){
        var me = this, 
            rectObject = {
                height: 0,
                width: 0,
                fillColor: '#A8A8A8',
                outlineColor: '#A8A8A8',
                active: false
            };


        return angular.merge({}, rectObject, data);
    }

    /**
    * Handles svg text creation
    */
    this.getSvgText = function(data){
        var me = this,
            text = data.text,
            stringArray = text.split('\n');

        if(text === ""){
            return null;
        }

        return stringArray;
    },

    /**
    * Get data for rect object
    */
    this.getSvgRectData = function(textArea, isActive, prevConfig){
        var me = this,
            box = textArea.getBBox(),
            defaultRectConfig =  {
                height: box.height,
                width: box.width,
                active: isActive
            },
            rectConfig = angular.merge({}, prevConfig, defaultRectConfig);

        return me.getSvgRectObject(rectConfig);
    },

    /**
    * 
    * @returns {Array}
    */
    this.getSvgRectListData = function(textAreaList, isActive, previousConfig){
        var me = this,
            active = isActive,
            previousRectConfig,
            result = [];

        angular.forEach(textAreaList, function(textArea, index) {
            if(previousConfig.rectConfig[index]){
                previousRectConfig = previousConfig.rectConfig[index];
            }

            result.push(me.getSvgRectData(textArea, active, previousRectConfig));
        });

        return result;
    }
}]);
```

**UPD 4: problem solution**

Seems I've got the solution.

Instead of this

```
var domText = $element.find('text'),
                textExampleList = domText,
                textConfig = $scope.svgConfig.textConfig,
                font = textConfig.fontFamily,
                size = textConfig.fontSize;

            document.fonts.load(''+size + 'px ' + font+'').then(
                function(){
                    $scope.setSvgRectanglesConfig(textExampleList);     
                }
            );
```

It should be something like this:

```
var textConfig = $scope.svgConfig.textConfig,
                font = textConfig.fontFamily,
                size = textConfig.fontSize;

            document.fonts.load(''+size + 'px ' + font+'').then(
                function(){
                    var textExampleList = $element.find('text');

                    $scope.setSvgRectanglesConfig(textExampleList);
                    $scope.$apply();        
                }
            );
```

I should have get dom data **after** font is loaded, but in old version I used old version of dom data. Also, I forgot about applying changes.

[image]

Comment: Can you show some more of your code? Maybe the `setSvgRectanglesConfig` function?

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert of course of course! updating it atm!

Comment: Updated. Tried to make it shorter as I could

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use the [Font Loading API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Font_Loading_API) for this:

```
var text = 'Text to display';
var font = 'Font to use';
document.fonts.load('12px "'+font+'"', text).then(function() {
  // Here we can be certain the font is available
  // Measure the size now…
});
```

Example:

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button');
var result = document.querySelector('div');

button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var text = 'The text to rénder';
  // This loads the font (unless already available)
  document.fonts.load('12px "Baloo Paaji"', text).then(function() {
    // Here we can be certain the font is available
    result.style.fontFamily = '"Baloo Paaji"';
    result.textContent = text;
  });
}, false);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Paaji" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <button>Load Font</button>
  <div></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Alternatively, you could just try to have all fonts pre-loaded by including a small snippet of text for each font somewhere (hidden) in the page.

Comment: Interesting. So it happens because of font loading and svg redering happens async?
First solution looks cool, I'll try it, thank you!
Second solution looks not good ._.

Comment: SVG rendering does not happen async: as soon as you access display properties, rendering needs to happen. But while the font hasn’t loaded, the metrics will be different because the text will be rendered in the fallback font.

Comment: @mzmm56 in then there is a call to function in my `controller` which is updates `$scope` fileds and it binded with directive like that

`<text ng-attr-font-family="{{scope.fontFamily}}">`

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert Thanks, Raphael! Your answer is really what I wanted!